# Это очень распространённое убеждение укрепилось в нём во многом благодаря своей простоте и логичности?

Tags: фраза

Правильно ли звучит эта фраза? Простота и логичность относится к убеждению. Но можно понять, что простота и логичность относятся к нему? Как можно перефразировать это предложение, если это необходимо? Спасибо.

Comment: По моему мнению, ничего не нужно перефразировать. Из фразы абсолютно ясно, что прилагательные относятся именно к убеждению. Двусмысленность могла бы возникнуть, если бы вместо `своей` использовалось `его`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правило простое, оно звучит так: *местоимение «свой» означает «относящийся к подлежащему»*. Поскольку в вашем предложении подлежащим является «убеждение», то ничего перефразировать не надо, всё понятно однозначно.

Answer (score 1):

Dmitry прав, никакой двусмысленности в утверждении нет. Двусмысленным было бы:

> Это очень распространённое убеждение укрепилось в нём во многом
>   благодаря **его** простоте и логичности

Answer (score 1):

Сочетание *в нём во многом* создаёт мимолётное впечатление однородных членов предложения, и возникает некоторая запинка в понимании.

Я бы переформулировал, но прежде обветил бы на вопрос: **во многом** — благодаря простоте и логичности, а **в остальном** — благодаря чему? Распространённости? Или чему-то неназванному в этом предложении? Нужно ли тут вообще это *во многом*?

Comment: Я описываю героя романа. Убеждение следующего характера: бог создал людей и забыл про них. Поэтому существуют грабежи, убийства и насилие. В остальном - потому что это черта характера такая у героя. Герой не верит в вездесущность бога, любовь, судьбу.